# Como é criado o arquivo de extensão .js que é utilizado pelo browser na abertura de páginas da web?

Tags: javascript, html, dreamweaver

Como é criado o arquivo de extensão .js que é utilizado pelo browser na abertura de páginas da web?

Estou estudando um site já criado para entender o sistema de funcionamento dos sites. Nos arquivos deste site, ao salvar a página da web completa, consigo encontrar uns arquivos .js, e gostaria de entender como ele é criado. Alguém pode me ajudar nisso?

Segunda pergunta: Qual o nome da linguagem deste arquivo?

Terceira pergunta: Este arquivo pode ser criado com o DreamWeaver?

Comment: **1**. Com um editor de texto (??); **2**. JavaScript; **3**. Sim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS é a extensão para JavaScript

E sim você pode criar arquivos JS utilizando qualquer editor de texto (DreamWeaver, Sublime, Atom, VIM, Bloco de Notas, etc.)

E para os arquivos .JS serem chamados em uma pagina o jeito mais simples é vc criar um arquivo .JS exemplo:
arquivo.js

E ai na sua index.html você pode chamar ele dessa maneira aqui

```
<script src="arquivo.js"></script>
```

E ai sua html fica algo parecido com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="arquivo.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>Oi Mundo</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

OBS: So lembrando que para isso funcionar o seu arquivo.js e o seu index.html tem de estar na raiz da mesma pasta.

Comment: E aí Vinícius, obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: Tranquilo qualquer dúvida so mandar =]
#KeepCoding

Comment: Você poderia me indicar algum lugar que eu possa aprender a linguagem contidas nos arquivos .js? Pois tenho conhecimento básico de html, css e também de programação em java, porém nunca tinha visto algo parecido com esta linguagem. Segue um breve trecho do texto contido em um arquivo .js: !function(c,p){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=c.document?p(c,!0):function(c)‌​{if(!c.document)thro‌​w Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return p(c)}:p(c)}

Comment: Um bom lugar para começar eu acho que pode ser o próprio treinamento que o google está liberando, completamente novo e inovador: https://google.dev/u/new