# É possível ler um arquivo .txt no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Se for possível, como faria isso? Possuo um arquivo chamado *versao.txt*, e preciso que o JavaScript leia ele e mostre seu conteúdo na tela. Alguém tem ideia de como faria isso?
PS: por favor gostaria de um código sem usar funções *json*.

Comment: relacionado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/221254/setar-um-arquivo-de-texto-no-servidor-a-ser-lido-sempre-que-executar-o-html-co/221264#221264

Comment: Onde está seu arquivo? No servidor ou no cliente?

Comment: no meu localhost, preciso testar primeiro com ele aqui, para depois passar para o server..

Comment: localhost tb é server... ou não? :)

Comment: Estou fritando a cabeça com isso, não me dou bem com Web >-<, desculpa

Comment: @Alis Estamos aqui pra aprender e se ajudar. Não tem que pedir desculpa =]

Comment: hum.. obrigada de verdade

Answer (score 5):

Creio que com uma simples `XMLHttpRequest` isso seja possível. Lembre-se que as requisições a servidores são assíncronas, portanto não são executadas na ordem que você lê o código. Por isso provemos sempre callbacks pra elas, que é o código que queremos que execute quando essa requisição voltar do servidor.

```js
//esta variável é um array de arrays. Cada posição do array
// é um array de duas posições. a primeira é uma URL, e a segunda um callback
var urls = [
  ['https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', mostrarNaTela],
  ['https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2', logarNoConsole],
  ['https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/3', escreverNaTela]
]

// #### estes são os callbacks. Eles também podem ser funções anônimas, mas para evitar o callback hell, prefiro assim
function mostrarNaTela(conteudo){ alert(conteudo); }
function logarNoConsole(conteudo) { console.log(conteudo); }
function escreverNaTela(conteudo) { document.write(conteudo); }
// #### fim dos callbacks

// esta função destrincha o array na posição pedida, pegando o callback e a url
function fazerRequest(url){
// variável dados é um array de duas posições
  var dados = urls[url];
  //uri é a url aonde farei a requisição
  var uri = dados[0];
  //callback é a função que será executada na volta da requisição
  var callback = dados[1];
  lerArquivo(uri, callback);
}

function lerArquivo(nome, callback)
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", nome, false);
    req.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(req.readyState === 4)
        {
            //verifica se a requisição foi bem sucedida
            if(req.status === 200 || req.status == 0)
            {
                callback(req.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    req.send(null);
}
```

```html
<button id="acao1" onclick="fazerRequest(0)">Mostrar na tela</button>
<button id="acao2" onclick="fazerRequest(1)">Mostrar no console</button>
<button id="acao3" onclick="fazerRequest(2)">Mostrar no HTML</button>
```

Comment: mas onde eu entro com o nome do meu arquivo?.... sinto muito não entendo muito sobre AJAX

Comment: Apenas substitua na invocação de `lerArquivo`. Vale lembrar que se a requisição for `cross-domain`, isto deve estar habilitado, caso contrário vai dar erro

Comment: Já prevendo a próxima pergunta, seria legal passar um callback pra essa função.

Comment: @bfavaretto editarei com alguns callbacks :)

Comment: Eu recomendaria um exemplo com `fetch` pois é mais sucinto, usa `Promise` e já devolve um objecto (no caso de ser um json)

Comment: @LauroMoraes não sou tão familiarizado com `Promises` a ponto de escrevê-las como resposta :( então optei por callbacks comuns mesmo

Comment: Do que vocês estão falando, gente sou muito nuub nessa área, sei que estão tentando me ajudar e agradeço muito mas não entendo nada... desculpa

Comment: @Alis Esse *callback* que o Artur incluiu na resposta você vai precisar, vai por mim. Você só terá acesso ao conteúdo do arquivo de dentro dessa função de callback.

Comment: @bfavaretto , Oque seria um callback hell?

Comment: @Alis um callback hell, ou inferno dos callbacks, é quando você cai em um emaranhado indistinguível de funções aninhadas, dá uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188656/o-que-%C3%A9-o-inferno-dos-callbacks

Comment: @bfavaretto , muito obrigada. Consegui de certa forma modificar o código para ficar da forma em que preciso. Agradeço muito sua disposição e sua gentileza em ajudar. Obrigada !!

Answer (score 1):

Embora `XMLHttpRequest` seja suportado pela maior gama de navegadores eu recomendaria o uso da [API Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) ela trabalha sobre `XMLHttpRequest` e é mais recente abstraindo em muito o trabalho pesado.

Como esta `API` utiliza [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) fica mais fácil tratar erros e exceções.

Um exemplo básico:

```js
var request = function(url) {

    fetch(url, {
        cache: 'reload' // definir o tipo de cache
    }).then(function(response) {
        if ( response.ok ) {
            // texto simples
            return response.text();
            // para transformar o `json` que é `string` para um `object`
            // javascript use `response.json()` que o próximo `then` retornará um `object`
        }
        // em caso de resposta "opaca" ou outros erros
        throw new Error('Fetch error, status code: ' + response.status);
    }).then(function(text) {
        // buscar elemento (div)
        var el = document.getElementById('container');
        // adicionar resultado (objeto para string)
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML += '<br>' + text;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // caso haja um erro... tratar aqui
    });

};
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');">adicionar ao elemento (div)</button>


<div id="container">Resultado:</div>
```

O suporte atual da [API Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch): (fonte: [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch))

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]